# "Filter volume has an unconnected output" FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I've looked at other posts about this but none of the flags seem to work with mine. Here is part of the bash script that runs the command and re-runs the script when there's an error, like when it disconnects.

```
cmd="ffmpeg \
    -stream_loop -1 -re -thread_queue_size 256 -i "$VIDEO" \
    -stream_loop -1 -re -thread_queue_size 256 -i "$AUDIO" \
    -re -thread_queue_size 256 -i "$AUDIO" \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:a]volume=0.0[a1]; \
    [aout]" -map 0:v:0 -map "[aout]" \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:>
    -acodec aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -threads 0 -b:a $AB \
    -f flv -rtmp_live live $URL/$KEY"

until $cmd ; do
        echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
        sleep 2
done
```

Then it keeps restarting when I run the bash script with the error

```
Filter volume has an unconnected output
```

Comment: While I don't see any obvious problem, why are you including `1:a` if muting it `[1:a]volume=0.0[a1]`?

Comment: @kesh thanks I removed one of the volume flags.

Comment: If that's the case, you don't need `amix` either. So you can `-map [a1]`. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: @kesh Yes I still do, I removed it and updated it in the question.